# Loopback middleware - how to access data in req object?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm just starting on the Loopback API framework, and would like to define a middleware that would pre-process the req data before passing it to the next function. But I don't know how to get access to the data in `req` object. Any help?

E.g.

```
function middleWareThatAddAPropertyToTheRequestJSON(req, res, next)  {
    // Of course I get undefined for req.data, but that's approximately what I want.
    req.data.somethingIWouldLikeToChange = "blahblahblah";
}
```

Edit:

That's how I create the app (in server.js)

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module)
    app.start();
});
```

part of the middleware.json (in the same directory with server.js)

```
...
"initial": {
...
   "./middleware/rest/middlewareThatAddAPropertyToTheRequestJSON": {}
},
...
```

middleware/rest/middlewareThatAddAPropertyToTheRequestJSON.js:

```
module.exports = function() {
    return function middlewareThatAddAPropertyToTheRequestJSON(req, res, next) {
        // TODO: add sth to the req
        next();
    };
};
```

Another Edit:

Perhaps I'm not being precise. I want to modify a POST request.

e.g. client posts:

{"a": "b"}

I want to add a key-value pair to the request. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that we can only read the request message through the `Readable.read()` method of the `req` object, which is an instance of `http.IncomingMessage` class (as mentioned in the [reference](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage)). And it seems (to me) impossible to modify the message. If we have to manipulate the request message in anyway, it is not going to be done through the `req` object. As mentioned by @IvanSchwarz, it's usually the case to do it in other steps e.g. before storing it into a DB, passing the message to whatever methods, etc.

Thanks for all your help :)